# VBScript: Expanding precision to 16 decimals to circumvent scientific notation?

Tags: vbscript, precision, scientific-notation

I've searched for this answer but cannot find anything for VBS.

For instance:

```
dim num
num = 1234567890123456 'a 16 digit number
msgbox num
```

Working with `num` in any way will result in the number being displayed in scientific notation.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 16 digit number is changed to a `Double` by VBScript because neither `Int`, nor `Long` can store that number. You can use the [FormatNumber](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/formatnumber.html) function to display it as an integer:

> FormatNumber(Expression, NumDigitsAfterDecimal, IncludeLeadingDigit,
>   UseParensForNegativeNumbers, GroupDigit)

```
num = 1234567890123456
msgbox FormatNumber(num, 0, -2, -2, false)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new and was unaware of the FormatNumber function.

Here is the actual code I'm using:

dim num
num = 4895390000000005
FormatNumber(num, 0, -2, -2, false)
msgbox num

the output is 4895390000000010

I'm assuming the parameters can modified to fix this. Any pointers?

Comment: Floating point numbers are not precise. Seems like 4895390000000005 cannot be accurately represented by a Double. You could treat it as a string e.g. `num = "4895390000000005": msgbox num`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the default textual representation of your number, request one explicitly.

```
msgbox FormatNumber(num, 2)
```

([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws343esk%28v=vs.84%29.aspx))

This, however, has nothing to do with how the number is [actually stored](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (as a `double`).