# Qtp add more than 15 strings or convert more than 15 strings

Tags: vbscript, qtp

Can someone please guide me on how to convert more than 6 characters into int? Because I need to do sum after convert to int. I tried so many ways like `CInt, CLng`, etc still throw exponential value.

```
Stroutput = 2018050302216556
Sum = Stroutput + 1
```

I tried to divide into sveral chuck using right function but it doesnt look good. Can be manage but I need another option. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript: Expanding precision to 16 decimals to circumvent scientific notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044057/vbscript-expanding-precision-to-16-decimals-to-circumvent-scientific-notation)

Comment: See this also --> https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23290/how-to-convert-exponential-number-to-normal-number-in-qtp

Comment: to be honest, that string looks like a date/timestamp of some kind - you might be as well creating the date and time parts separately and then concatenating them.  Would make it simple to increment/decrement as required.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be working with a Date Structure, which as VBS says - hard to represent as numbers only. Use the CDate to get a date object from the string (If needed change the representation of that string to `(YYYY-mm-dd ...)`. With the DateAdd method you can add days, years etc; and finally the FormatDateTime will create an output of your wish.